# .net-core authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm going to authenticate the user by the help of .net-core version 2.
after registration, "SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." err will be appeared on signInManager method.

I've checked nullable datas and required datas in my model and database.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task < IActionResult > Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null) {
  ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
   var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

   var user = new ApplicationUser {
    Email = model.Email
   };

   // ...
```

startup.cs file

```
IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot;
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
 configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
 services.AddIdentity < ApplicationUser, IdentityRole > ()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores < ApplicationDbContext > ()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

 services.AddTransient < ApplicationDbContext > ();
 services.AddTransient < IEmailSender, AuthMessageServices > ();
 services.AddAuthentication();
 services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
 if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  app.UseBrowserLink();
 } else {
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
 }

 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.UseMvc(routes => {
  routes.MapRoute(
   name: "default",
   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
}
```

Comment: This is probably a problem with either your setup in startup.cs or in the database you are connecting to. Could you show how you are initializing security in startup.cs?

Comment: @GlennSills startup.cs attached to the post

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's the core 1.x way of implementing Identity Server auth. In core 2.x you implement identity as a service rather than a middleware.

Comment: Do you check whether the `signInManager` is correct? What does your dbcontext look like since you register it as `services.AddTransient < ApplicationDbContext > ();`?

Comment: after clicking on account verification, this issue will be appeared. more over, this issue will be happened after login time if user email exists on DB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to initialize ApplicationDbContext

`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`